# Find distinct cells from two columns and remove others in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet with around 1500 rows and 30 columns. Each row is a case with an associated ID in column A. Column B contains case references i.e. references to other cases. I would like to find all distinct cases (there are duplicates in column A and B) and their associated reference. Here's an example:

```
Column A (IDs)          Column B (References)       ....
1182250                 1367891
1182827                 1374095
1182827                 1374095
1182827                 1374095
1183167                 1377723
1183693                 1373384
1183693                 1373384
1184002                 1372448
1184015                 1407464
```

As you can see above, the ID 1182827 has three references
How can I associate/link the ID (1183724) to the most recent reference (the date is given in another column - let's say column C to make it easy to understand)? The reason as to why I want to do this is because I want to place the IDs from column A together with **one** (the most recent) reference from column B in a separate sheet. I was thinking about using the "remove duplicates" feature, but I am unsure of how to make Excel only take the most recent reference (based off date in column C). The end product would ideally look something like this:

```
Column A (IDs)          Column B (References)       ....
1182250                 1367891
1182827                 1374095
1183167                 1377723
1183693                 1373384
1184002                 1372448
1184015                 1407464
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a formula like this:

```
=FILTER($A$2:$C$10,$C$2:$C$10=MAXIFS($C$2:$C$10,$A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10))
```

So, we are filtering the range `A2:C10` where the value in column C is equal to the maximum value in column C for the ID on the current row.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **Excel 365**, then pick a cell and enter:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:B10)
```

[image]

As you see above, `UNIQUE()` can also perform limited filtering.

Comment: Sadly I don't, but thanks for your answer.